# How do I use the Cherokee keyboard layout to type English characters?

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen, onscreen-keyboard

Wow, I've really done it this time. I've locked myself out of my machine.

In preparing for a Cherokee language course, I added the Cherokee keyboard layout to my options. However, I was unable to generate any Cherokee characters by selecting that input device.

I found an article on the web which instructed me to use the `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command in a terminal.

Once I did that, I rebooted as instructed. Once I was presented with the login screen, I entered my password as usual only for it to fail.

After failing a few times, I gave my attention to what is usually a mundane exercise (i.e., logging in).  While I carefully entered my password, each time, I get the message, "Sorry that didn't work..."

So, I brought up the onscreen keyboard... But the password box displays an asterisk for only the first character of my password.

I attempted to use the direct Unicode input method (ctrl-shift-Uxxxx) but the Cherokee keyboard has no "U" key.

Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: The discussion at [bug #1725676](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1725676) deals with a similar problem.

Comment: I had already tried the Unicode input technique; alas, the Cherokee keyboard has no "U" preventing this. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave you a hint on the bug report, but probably there is an easier way, i.e. booting in recovery mode, getting a root prompt and remounting the system in read/write mode.

The details are explained in answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006). You don't actually need to reset the password, but rather edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. But besides that, the steps in the answers apply.

Comment: I truly appreciate your hints...

Comment: I spent the day learning new things after having been so fearful that I'd have to take a drastic measure like rebuilding my system.  @Gunnar, you are the best.  ᏩᏙ (which is Cherokee for "Thank you)!!

Comment: @TheGeeko61: Great to hear that you made it work again.